# Reading Data Attributes = Undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have code that looks like this:

```
<ul class="effects-list">
   <li data-creative="1">Creative</li>
   <li data-uplifted="3">Uplifted</li>
   <li data-energetic="3">Energetic</li>
</ul>
```

Then Javascript to read the data attributes:

```
$(function() {

  var effectData = $('.effects-list li');
  var creative = effectData.data("creative");
  var uplifted = effectData.data("uplifted");
  var energetic = effectData.data("energetic");

  console.log(creative);
  console.log(uplifted);
  console.log(energetic);

});
```

I end up with this in the console log:

```
1
undefined
undefined
```

Why is the script reading the information in the first `li` element but not the second two?

What do I have wrong and how do I solve the problem?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPCyC/) with the code above. I am using jQuery 2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the getter version of `data()`, it will look only at the first element in the given set, which does not have the said data attributes.

[.data(key)](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-*
>   attribute.

The solution is to use an attribute exists selector to target the correct element then fetch the data value. something like

```
var uplifted = effectData.filter('[data-uplifted]').data("uplifted");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LEC8A/)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Wasn't aware of that. Learn something new everyday. => Thank You for the help.